# Can we display the records in Visualforce page. If the object is private at OWD?

Tags: apex, visualforce, owd

I have an object which is private at OWD. I am trying to display all the user's records of that object in the Visualforce page. Is it possible? How to display?

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the user's profile contains the *Read <Object>* permission (where *Object* is the object you'd like to display), you can display those records in a Visualforce page. By default, with *Private* sharing, users can only see their own records, records of users below them, and any records shared with them. As a generic example, the following code shows the user every account they can view:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" readOnly="true" recordSetVar="records">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Account List" />
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!records}" var="record">
            <apex:column value="{!record.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!record.Industry}" />
            <apex:column value="{!record.BillingState}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

If you need more complicated logic, you might need to also write a controller or extension, but the principle remains the same.